# Draw on canvas wherever view is dragged

Tags: android, canvas, draggable, android-drawable

I am trying to create a simple paint app using canvas. The end product would be for the user to select a tool of choice (pen, marker, eraser, etc) and draw or erase accordingly anywhere the tool is dragged on the canvas.

As of now, I only have a pen and I am trying to draw a line wherever the pen is dragged in the canvas. However, I am finding this task challenging. I can drag the pen and I can draw lines, but I can't draw while I am dragging the pen. I am reaching out to the SO community to bridge these two features.

Below is what I have:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ViewGroup rootLayout;
private int _xDelta;
private int _yDelta;
private RelativeLayout pl;
private ImageView w1;
private boolean clicked1 = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    CanvasView canvasView = new CanvasView(MainActivity.this);

    w1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.wand1);
    pl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordAct);
    RelativeLayout rootLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordAct);

    rootLayout.addView(canvasView);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1w2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(getScreenWidth(), getScreenHeight() / 2);
    layoutParams1w2.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    canvasView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1w2);

    w1.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
}

public static int getScreenWidth() {
    return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
}

public static int getScreenHeight() {
    return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
}

public class ChoiceTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        if (!clicked1){
            rootLayout = (ViewGroup) w1.getParent();
            if (rootLayout != null) {
                // detach the child from parent
                rootLayout.removeView(w1);
            }
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(300, 300);
            pl.addView(w1);

            w1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1);
            clicked1 = true;
        }
        final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
        final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();

        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                _xDelta = X - lParams.leftMargin;
                _yDelta = Y - lParams.topMargin;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view
                        .getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
                layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
                layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
                layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
                view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                break;
        }
        rootLayout.invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

CanvasView.java

```
public class CanvasView extends View{
Context context;
int width, height;
Bitmap bitmap;
Path path;
Canvas canvas;
Paint paint;
float mX, mY;
static final float TOLERANCE=4;
public CanvasView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context=context;
    path=new Path();
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(50);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w,h,oldw,oldh);
    bitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(w,h,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    canvas=new Canvas(bitmap);
}

public void startTouch(float x, float y) {
    path.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
}

public void moveTouch(float x, float y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x-mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y-mY);

    if(dx>=TOLERANCE || dy>= TOLERANCE) {
        path.quadTo(mX, mY, (x+mX)/2, (y+mY)/2);
        mX=x;
        mY=y;
    }
}

//To clear canvas
public void clearCanvas() {
    path.reset();
    invalidate();
}

public void upTouch() {
    path.lineTo(mX,mY);
}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawPath(path,paint);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction())
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            startTouch(x,y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            moveTouch(x,y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            upTouch();
            invalidate();
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/coordAct"
tools:context="com.simplepaintapp.MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/parLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:background="#0000ff">



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
        android:background="#BA9DF7"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/backgd"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/parentLL"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="5">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/wand1"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/pen" />


            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

[Current bug after implementing the dispatchTouchEvent() method inside onTouch()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsBtH.png)

Comment: You have 2 different places handling TouchEvents and both are returning true in the instances you care about. Returning true signals that you have consumed the `TouchEvent` and it doesn't need to go any further.

Comment: @BryanDormaier So you are saying to just combine onTouchEvent() with onTouch() method?

Comment: No you have two different views handling Touch. If you want them to be able to work with each other you need to determine when you should be returning true on either to signify that you are indeed consuming the `TouchEvent`.

Another pattern would be to `dispatchTouchEvent()` from one view to the other, but as it stands now the two places you handle touch are competing with each other.

Comment: @BryanDormaier ah! I see what you are getting at. So because I am returning true on both onTouch and onTouchEvent, only one will execute...whichever action is met first, draw or drag. If I want to implement the dispatchTouchEvent() method, would I just have to call canvasView.dispatchTouchEvent()?

Comment: If you wanted to pass that view on from w1, it should be something like canvasView.dispatchTouchEvent(event)

Comment: @BryanDormaier You are wonderful! However, there is a little bug. When the pen is being dragged, the marks on the canvas are nowhere near where the pen is being dragged.For example, the pen is dragged on the left side of the Mobile screen, but the marks are all the way to the right side of the screen. I added canvasView.dispatchTouchEvent(event); inside the onTouch method.

Comment: I uploaded a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsBtH.png.

Comment: I got it! I couldn't have done it without your help, @BryanDormaier! For anyone else having this problem, dispatchTouchEvent(event) is the answer. I will be posting my solution soon.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out! There are a few tricks to figuring out touch when you have layers so glad I could give you a nudge in the right direction to start figuring out how they work.

Answer (score 0):

An update to MainActivity and CanvasView is required. See the new source code below:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ViewGroup rootLayout;
private int _xDelta;
private int _yDelta;
private RelativeLayout pl;
private ImageView w1;
private boolean clicked1 = false;
CanvasView canvasView;
public static int X;
public static int Y;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    canvasView = new CanvasView(MainActivity.this);

    w1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.wand1);
    pl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordAct);
    RelativeLayout rootLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordAct);

    rootLayout.addView(canvasView);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1w2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(getScreenWidth(), getScreenHeight() / 2);
    layoutParams1w2.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    canvasView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1w2);

    w1.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
}

public static int getScreenWidth() {
    return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
}

public static int getScreenHeight() {
    return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
}

public class ChoiceTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

        if (!clicked1){
            rootLayout = (ViewGroup) w1.getParent();
            if (rootLayout != null) {
                // detach the child from parent
                rootLayout.removeView(w1);
            }
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(300, 300);
            pl.addView(w1);

            w1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1);
            clicked1 = true;
        }
        X = (int) event.getRawX();
        Y = (int) event.getRawY();

        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                _xDelta = X - lParams.leftMargin;
                _yDelta = Y - lParams.topMargin;
                canvasView.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view
                        .getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
                layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
                layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
                layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
                view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                canvasView.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
                break;
        }
        rootLayout.invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

CanvasView.java:

```
public class CanvasView extends View{
Context context;
int width, height;
Bitmap bitmap;
Path path;
public Canvas canvas;
Paint paint;
float mX, mY;
static final float TOLERANCE=4;
public static float x;
public static float y;
public CanvasView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context=context;
    path=new Path();
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(50);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w,h,oldw,oldh);
    bitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(w,h,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    canvas=new Canvas(bitmap);
}

public void startTouch(float x, float y) {
    path.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
}

public void moveTouch(float x, float y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x-mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y-mY);

    if(dx>=TOLERANCE || dy>= TOLERANCE) {
        path.quadTo(mX, mY, (x+mX)/2, (y+mY)/2);
        mX=x;
        mY=y;
    }
}

//To clear canvas
public void clearCanvas() {
    path.reset();
    invalidate();
}

public void upTouch() {
    path.lineTo(mX,mY);
}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawPath(path,paint);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();
    switch (event.getAction())
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            startTouch(MainActivity.X,MainActivity.Y-380);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            moveTouch(MainActivity.X,MainActivity.Y-380);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            upTouch();
            invalidate();
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```